# Figuring out the algorithm for an NFC reader, which displays values increased by 1.52 times

Tags: encryption, xor

I have two NFC readers, reader A reads card ID numbers according to the ISO standard and the algorithm is publicly available. Reader B is from a Canon printer. The card numbers read by reader B are 1.52 times larger than those read by reader A for the same card.

Is there a genius who can help me figure out the encryption algorithm of the NFC reader B?

---

Here are some card data for reference.

---

card1:
reader A：0565932061
reader B：0863528701

card2:
readerA：0100347102
readerB：0153111486

card3:
readerA：1816830668
readerB：2772241676

card4:
readerA：1530064599
readerB：2363059447

card5:
readerA：3783796822
readerB：5773610326

---

my card is standard mifare m1 card.
reader B is from cannon c5560i printer.
According to the ISO14443-a standard：The first four bytes of my card is 1D 70 BB 21, reversing the orde gives 21 BB 70 1D which is the value 565932061 in decimal.

so:
reader A：0565932061 ：ISO standard

reader B：0863528701 ：unknown

As you can see the value B shows is approximately 1.52 times more，So I think it's possible to find an algorithm compared to those with irregular encryption.

Who can help me figure out the encryption algorithm of the NFC reader B?

Comment: Ratio in all cases except 4 (does case 4 contain a typo?) are close to constant `0.65536` which is easy to divide by in a microcontroller (multiplying by `10^5/2^16`).  Probably this is a way to hide a card no from you :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Figuring out the algorithm for an NFC reader, which displays values increased by 1.52 times](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/32259/figuring-out-the-algorithm-for-an-nfc-reader-which-displays-values-increased-by)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have found the algorithm